# How to get Locale in Webflux Functional Endpoints?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I am using Spring's [Functional Endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-fn) with Kotlin to create a web service, and I'm trying to figure out the idiomatic way to resolve the `Locale` off using the standard `Accept-Language` header.

Here's an example of what the code looks like:

```kotlin
val repository: PersonRepository = ...
val handler = PersonHandler(repository)

val route = coRouter { 
    GET("/person", handler::getPeople)
}

class PersonHandler(private val repository: PersonRepository) {

    suspend fun getPeople(request: ServerRequest): ServerResponse {
        val locale = /* ??? */
        // create and return response
    }

}
```

Spring documentation references using a [`LocaleContextResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/i18n/LocaleContextResolver.html) that resolves the `Locale` as part of the request, but I don't see a way to use it when using Functional Endpoints. You can get the *raw* values passed into the `Accept-Language` header off of [`ServiceRequest.headers().acceptLanguage()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/server/ServerRequest.Headers.html#acceptLanguage--) like so...

```kotlin
suspend fun getPeople(request: ServerRequest): ServerResponse {
    val locale = 
        Locale.lookup(request.headers().acceptLanguage(), supportedLocales)
        ?: Locale.getDefault()
    // create and return response
}
```

.... but isn't that just reimplementing the responsibility of `LocaleContextResolver` in every single Handler Function?

**What is the idiomatic way to convert the `Accept-Language` header into the single/best supported `Locale` within Spring's Functional Endpoints?**

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with a [`before`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.5/kdoc-api/spring-framework/org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server/-co-router-function-dsl/before.html) filter:

```kotlin
val repository: PersonRepository = ...
val handler = PersonHandler(repository)

val route = coRouter { 
    GET("/person", handler::getPeople)
    before(::parseLocale)
}

fun parseLocale(request: ServerRequest): ServerRequest {
    val locale = try {
        Locale.lookup(request.headers().acceptLanguage(), wellKnownSupportedLocales) ?: wellKnownDefaultLocale
    } catch (exception: RuntimeException) {
        wellKnownDefaultLocale
    }

    return ServerRequest
        .from(request)
        .attribute("locale", locale)
        .body(request.bodyToFlux())
        .build()
}

class PersonHandler(private val repository: PersonRepository) {

    suspend fun getPeople(request: ServerRequest): ServerResponse {
        val locale = request.attributes("locale").get() as Locale
        // create and return response
    }

}
```